# Javascript - Append once in condition check in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have an array `mainTitle` that I am attempting to check if the string exists in `listOfTitles` then append to `#mainTitle`. If not then append to `#otherTitle`. In order to achieve this, I am looping through the array `listOfTitles` in order to check if any of the strings match with the first index of `mainTitle`

My issue is that string appends for every time the check fails due to the length of the array I am looping through. In this example, `"Online"` should only appear once in blue text, and `"Retail"` and `"Store"` which doesn't exist in `listOfTitles` should only appear once in red text.

I am attempting to have the string append-only once. How can I achieve with when needing to increment through the entire array in order to check if there is a match?

My expected outcome is to have only **1** `"Online", "Retail", and "Store"` to append and not the length of the string.

```js
const mainTitle = ["Online", "Retail", "Store"]

const listOfTitles = ["Test","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5","Test6", "Online", "Test7"]


for (let i = 0; i < mainTitle.length; i++) {
 

checkMatch(mainTitle[i])

};

function checkMatch (title) {

for (let i = 0; i < listOfTitles.length; i++) {

if (title=== listOfTitles[i]) {
$("#mainTitle").append(title);
} else {
$("#otherTitle").append(title);
}


}

}
```

```css
#mainTitle {
color:blue;
}

#otherTitle {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainTitle"> </div>
<div id="otherTitle"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be appending because every time the loop runs, something will get added. Instead, just replace the contents of the target element with the new results.

```js
const mainTitle = ["Online", "Retail", "Store"]
const listOfTitles = ["Test","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5","Test6", "Online", "Test7"]
for (let i = 0; i < mainTitle.length; i++) {
  checkMatch(mainTitle[i])
};

function checkMatch (title) {
  for (let i = 0; i < listOfTitles.length; i++) {
    if (title=== listOfTitles[i]) {
      $("#mainTitle").text(title);
    } else {
      // Only append if the title is not already in the element
      if(!$("#otherTitle").text().includes(title)){
        $("#otherTitle").append(title);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#mainTitle {
  color:blue;
}

#otherTitle {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainTitle"></div>
<div id="otherTitle"></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what the else code is doing? Starting with the comment `Only append if the title is not already in the element`